# cmake: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I'm trying to build [this project](https://github.com/Canjie-Luo/Text-Image-Augmentation) , on Google Colab ( [link to notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MAA_MbySiYMpk07FceDfu0ycdxWtwZhG?usp=sharing) ), the listed requirements are:

> GCC 4.8.* Python 2.7.* Boost 1.67 OpenCV 2.4.*

the `CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall -std=c++11")

# Head and source
include_directories(include)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(src DIR_SRCS)

# Find necessary packages
find_package( PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

find_package( Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR} )

# Define the wrapper library
add_library(Augment SHARED ${DIR_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(Augment ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} Augment)

# Don't prepend wrapper library name with lib
set_target_properties(Augment PROPERTIES PREFIX "" )
```

EDIT:with the original cmakelists I get

`/usr/include/python2.7` for `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS` ,

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so` for `PYTHON_LIBRARIES`

`/usr/local/include` for `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR`

`Boost::python` for `Boost_LIBRARIES`

having no experience in c ,I ran into a couple of errors during `make`

the first is:

> fatal error: numpy/ndarrayobject.h: No such file or directory

runnung `!find /usr/ -name ndarrayobject.h` outputs:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_python/numpy_include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h
/usr/local/pkgs/numpy-base-1.19.2-py37hfa32c7d_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h
```

so I tried replacing this:

```
find_package( PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

with:

```
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/lib/python2.7)
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

which works I guess but now this error is raised:

> fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

running `!find /usr/include -name pyconfig.h` outputs:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6m/pyconfig.h
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/pyconfig.h
```

how to solve this error ? and i'm quite sure another error will be raised when cmake fails to find opencv 2.4

you can play around with the notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MAA_MbySiYMpk07FceDfu0ycdxWtwZhG?usp=sharing)

Comment: maybe you should use `include_directories( /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/ )` and keep original `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS` which would have many folders.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. the notebook link you provide has permission issues; 2. try `message(FATAL_ERROR ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})` and tell us the error output. It helps debug all the time; 3. It's a pain in the ass to work with code that begins with `cmake_minimum_required` 2.6.0. It's year 2021 and cmake 3.19.4 as we speak. Poorly written CMakeLists are just begging for error.

Comment: @TerryTsao thanks for notifying me about the notebook's permissions, now it's not restricted,, I commented out the line `cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6.0)` and same error occurs, I changed it to version 3.19 and still the same error.

Comment: @TerryTsao with the original `cmakelists` containing `find_package( PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED )` I get `/usr/include/python2.7` for `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS` ,, and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so` for `PYTHON_LIBRARIES`

Comment: @furas thanks for your answer, with your suggestion i'm back to the `numpy/ndarrayobject.h: No such file` error